# A Primer on Orthogonal GARCH Model Covariance Matrix

Tags: covariance, garch, orthogonal

I am trying to replicate Table 3a: Correlation Matrix from this paper (Page 11): http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.201.7226&rep=rep1&type=pdf. (I believe there is a mistake and should be the Co-variance Matrix).

That said, they are based on the returns to three stocks in the CAC 40: Paribus, SocGen and Danone using daily data 1st Jan 1994 to 9th Feb 1999. However, I am not sure why I cant replicate the results. Below is my python code and results:

```
cac = pd.read_csv('Paribus_SocGen_Danone.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
cac.pct_change().cov()

>>>     BNP         SocGen      Danone
BNP     0.749331    0.137695    0.196612
SocGen  0.137695    0.573397    0.047025
Danone  0.196612    0.047025    0.288345
```

Great if someone can help me on this. Thanks.